Apollo GraphQL & Swift: Dealing with null values in query
I finished watching some videos on how to use GraphQL in iOS. I'm trying to practice writing queries and I thought maybe I would use PokeAPI GraphQL to solidify my newly acquired knowledge. This is how my query looks like.
query GetAllPokemon {
  pokemon_v2_pokemon(order_by: {pokemon_species_id: asc}) {
    name
    id
    sprites: pokemon_v2_pokemonsprites {
      home: sprites(path: "other.home.front_default")
      showdown: sprites(path: "other.showdown.front_default")
      officialArtwork: sprites(path: "other.official-artwork.front_default")
    }
    pokemon_species_id
  }
}

This query works in the PokeAPI GraphiQL interface. But it doesn't work when I call it in my swift project.This is how I'm calling it in Xcode.
Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: GetAllPokemonQuery()) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let graphResult):
        print("success")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
        print("error")
    }
}

But I'm getting this error below.
GraphQLExecutionError(path: pokemon_v2_pokemon.32.sprites.0.home, underlying: ApolloAPI.JSONDecodingError.nullValue)

The error tells me that it has to do with how ApolloAPI is decoding the JSON since some of the values in the query can be null. How would I be able to fix the JSONDecoding if it's done by ApolloAPI.
I was thinking of just fetching the Sprites using the REST endpoint instead. But I really want to know if there's a way to get this to work in Xcode.
Edit:
Made the question more clear
Steps to reproduce the error

Import apollo-ios package using the following link https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios.git

Install Apollo Cli by right clicking the project. 

Create a new file GetAllPokemon.graphql and copy the query from above and paste it into this file & close Xcode.

Open terminal and cd to the project and run the terminal init command from below.

The following command should have created a file 'apollo-codegen-config.json now open it and replace it with config JSON from below.

Run the following terminal commands to fetch schema first then the generate command from below. This should have created 2 folders: graphql & PokeAPI.

Now open Xcode add a new package. Select local and select the PokeAPI folder and add package. Now copy & paste the finished code from below & you will get the error.


Snippets
Config JSON
{
  "schemaNamespace" : "PokeAPI",
  "input" : {
    "operationSearchPaths" : [
      "**/*.graphql"
    ],
    "schemaSearchPaths" : [
      "**/*.graphqls"
    ]
  },
  "output" : {
    "testMocks" : {
      "none" : {
      }
    },
    "schemaTypes" : {
      "path" : "./PokeAPI",
      "moduleType" : {
        "swiftPackageManager" : {
        }
      }
    },
    "operations" : {
      "inSchemaModule" : {
      }
    }
  },
  "schemaDownloadConfiguration": {
      "downloadMethod": {
          "introspection": {
              "endpointURL": "https://beta.pokeapi.co/graphql/v1beta",
              "httpMethod": {
                  "POST": {}
              },
              "includeDeprecatedInputValues": false,
              "outputFormat": "SDL"
          }
      },
      "downloadTimeout": 60,
      "headers": [],
      "outputPath": "./graphql/schema.graphqls"
  }
}

Terminal init command
./apollo-ios-cli init --schema-namespace PokeAPI --module-type swiftPackageManager

Terminal fetch schema command
./apollo-ios-cli fetch-schema

Terminal generate command
./apollo-ios-cli generate  

Finished Code
import SwiftUI
import PokeAPI
import Apollo

class Network {
    static let shared = Network()
    
    private(set) lazy var apollo = ApolloClient(url: URL(string: "https://beta.pokeapi.co/graphql/v1beta")!)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {}
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: GetAllPokemonQuery()) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let graphQLResult):
                    print("Success: \(graphQLResult)")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Failure: \(error)")
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code .
Show the code for GetAllPokemonQuery() and any relevant code so we can compile and run it.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I added the steps that reproduces the error.
